# How I can set DispatcherTimer into the for loop

Tags: wpf, multithreading

I am using wpf DispatcherTimer and I want ot use it into the for loop how i can use it..

my code is here..

```
        DispatcherTimer timer = new DispatcherTimer();

        timer.Tick += (s, e) =>
        {
            for (i = 0; i < 10; i++)
            {
                obsValue.Add(new Entities(i));
                timer.Interval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30);
                timer.Start();
            }
        };
```

Thanks....

Comment: What are you trying to do ? The code and the question doesn't reveal your intent. The tick event handler would be called periodically (based on specified interval).

Comment: I want to add record one by one into the DataGrid.into the for loop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you start a timer with `Interval` set to `30 seconds`, its `Tick` event will be raised every 30 seconds.

Now, what I understand from your question is you want to add a record every 30 seconds.

Here is what you can do. Note that it does not require a `for loop` but you still need to maintain current index. To do that, you can use a `private field` or a `local variable with lambda`.

### Example:

```
    DispatcherTimer timer = new DispatcherTimer();
    timer.Interval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30);
    
    Int32 index = 0, maxValue = 10;

    timer.Tick += (s, e) =>
    {                
        obsValue.Add(new Entities(index));
        index ++; // increment index

        // Stop if this event has been raised max number of times
        if(index > maxValue) timer.Stop();
    };

    timer.Start();
```

Comment: it's good but it will not working on the stop it will goes to the infinite times..

Comment: Check updated code, and put a breakpoint on `timer.Stop()` and see if it hits. If not, try to find out why.

Answer (score 1):

I think you misunderstand how the DispatcherTimer works. Once you invoke Start(), the Tick event will be fired each time the Interval has been reached, i.e. you start it and it ticks repeatedly. Your code should look like this instead:

```
    DispatcherTimer timer = new DispatcherTimer();
    timer.Interval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30);
    timer.Start();

    timer.Tick += (s, e) =>
    {
        for (i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            obsValue.Add(new Entities(i));
        }
    };
```

This will add 10 new Entities, every 30 seconds.